# problems when booting ubuntu 14

Tags: 14.04, usb

When ubuntu load, it's show message

`usb 1-1.1: string descriptor 0 read error: -22`

and then else

```
usb 1-1.1: string descriptor 0 read error: -22
[drm:cpt_set_fifo_underrun_reporting] *ERROR* uncleared pch underrun on pch transcoder A
[drm:cpt_serr_int_handler] *ERROR* PCH transcoder A FIFO underrun
usb 1-1.1: string descriptor 0 read error: -22
```

so my laptop freezes after 20 - 30 minute :(

Answer (score 0):

Restart your machine, in the GRUB menu, go to the recovery option and follow the on-screen instructions. If repairing does not fix your problem, select the option to drop to a root shell inside the recovery mode and post the output of lsusb.

Comment: after `lsusb` [info](https://scontent-fra3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xfp1/v/t1.0-9/10885290_1010324475674226_4784138973514816218_n.jpg?oh=0b7b95da6eaba6aa892759581cbf15aa&oe=56499897)